# trying to run laravel homestead with vagrant

Tags: windows-10, vagrant

So I did `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` in my home directory (C:\Users\User Name) and got the following back:

```
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    box: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.5.0) for provider: virtualbox
    box: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.5.0/providers/virtualbox.box
    box: Progress: 100% (Rate: 11.3M/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
==> box: Successfully added box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.5.0) for 'virtualbox'!
```

I then, in that directory, do `vagrant up` and get the following error:

```
A Vagrant environment or target machine is required to run this
command. Run `vagrant init` to create a new Vagrant environment. Or,
get an ID of a target machine from `vagrant global-status` to run
this command on. A final option is to change to a directory with a
Vagrantfile and to try again.
```

Do I need to do `vagrant init`? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead doesn't make any mention of it. Based on my Google searches it seems like `vagrant init` is for creating new boxes from scratch - not for re-using boxes you downloaded..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I needed to do `vagrant init laravel/homestead` after doing `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`. Seems like it'd be prudent for https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead to mention that..